# Highscores are not being added

Tags: game-maker, game-maker-studio-2

I'm making a game and I wanted to add a top 3 scoreboard, so I'm using the built-in highscore system that game maker has, but when I add the highscore and use a message box to display the score just after adding it, it doesn't output it

I've tried testing to see if the score is bigger than the top 3 and insert it into there but that doesn't work for me

Heres the code I'm using without testing to see if it should be on the top 3

```java
if(keyboard_string != ""){
    highscore_add(keyboard_string,score);
    show_message("Added highscore");
    show_message(highscore_name(0) + ": " + string(highscore_value(0)));
    keyboard_string = "";
}
```

It checks to see if you have typed a name and then adds it to the scores list, (Its in a bigger if statement for when you press enter on the gameover screen)

The message box after "Added highscore" should show the top score and the name attached to it, instead, it shows the "Added highscore" and then ": 0".

If the message boxes are working then there should be a top score at least (why I'm printing the top one) I changed it to

```
show_message(highscore_name(1) + ": " + string(highscore_value(1)));
```

and it then printed ": 0"

I have no clue why it's not adding any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I will be honest, using the included save system is pretty bad (it's bassically a savestate system more than a save), i will recommend using a .ini save system, i'ts really simple one you get how it works, i'm going to leave a link to a good tutorial that teaches the basics of how to use ini.

Here's the link: https://gdpalace.wordpress.com/2016/07/03/ini_files_save_load/